# Difference between settings in .vscode.settings.json and settings in .vscode.workspace.code-workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to understand the mechanics of VS Code and am currently looking at settings files. Whilst the difference between user settings and workspace settings is well explained in a number of posts on SO I'm confused about having settings inside both a `settings.json` file and inside a `workspace.code-workspace` file in the `.vscode` folder in my project folder.

Sample from `settings.json`:

```
{
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": ["tests"],
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/Users/me/opt/miniconda3/envs/capra/bin/python",
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [],
    "editor.rulers": [79],
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled": false,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
    },
}
```

Sample from `workspace.code-workspace`:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "name": "polgara",
            "path": ".."
        },
    ],
    "settings": {
        "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
        "git.confirmSync": false,
        "window.zoomLevel": -1,
        "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
        "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
        "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
        "python.formatting.provider": "black",
        "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file",
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": true,
        },
    }
}
```

I've gone through the [settings page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) on the VS Code site and they make reference to user and workspace settings files but not to having settings inside the `workspace.code-workspace` file.

Could someone explain why there are settings in both the `settings.json` file and the `workspace.code-workspace` file?

Comment: it all depends on the scope you want to give your setting, you can overrule a setting by defining it in a more local scope **Default** > **User/Global** > **Multi Root Workspace** > **Folder/Workspace**. Be aware that setting objects are merged not overruled

Comment: Hey. Do the two files cover different scopes then? `settings.json` is for the project folder and `workspace.code-workspace` is for the entire workspace? I believe workspace settings overrule user settings...

Comment: you have a global `settings.json` and you have a `.vscode/settings.json` in each workspace, I say the same thing about overrule

Comment: Hi. I'm still confused I'm afraid. I was trying to understand the difference between the `.vscode/settings.json` file and the settings in `.vscode/workspace.code-workspace`? What are the scope differences between these two files?

Comment: `.vscode/workspace.code-workspace` is the wrong place to store your Multi Root workspace, it does not BELONG to that particular workspace, it contains settings that apply to all workspaces in the MR Workspace, and you can overrule these settings with settings in `.vscode/settings.json`, https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration

Comment: Ok I think I'm starting to understand - the `.vscode/workspace.code-workspace` is a multi-root workspace for where there are multiple folders within a workspace - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces#_multiroot-workspaces. If this file shouldn't be in `.vscode` where should it go?

Comment: the `.vscode` folder is part of some WorkspaceFolder A, not the location to store the MR Workspace file, WorkspaceFolder A is one of the workspaces (sub projects) of the MR Workspace, each WorkspaceFolder can have its own git repo